# LateInitializationError: Field 'loggedInEmployee' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to load in the details of an employee that I saved in storage via SharedPreferences before making any requests to my API to make requests.

This is the last thing I have tried

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    loggedInEmployee =
        Employee.fromJson(jsonDecode(prefs.getString("employee")!));
  });
  _loadDayTemplates();
}
```

Other things I have tried include making a Future function that returns the Employee object and put that in my initState() function, as well as trying to pass through the employee object from SharedPreferences through from a previous page. None of these solutions have worked so far unfortunately, the page always seems to be loaded in before the employee object is actually present.

Are there any other things I could try to fix this?

Comment: Can you include code-snippet instead of code-image?

Comment: `@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      loggedInEmployee =
          Employee.fromJson(jsonDecode(prefs.getString("employee")!));
    });
    _loadDayTemplates();
  }`

Comment: Can you try with adding `setState((){})` after the initializing `loggedInEmployee `

Comment: Still the same error unfortunately after adding that :(

Comment: also try Including `_loadDayTemplates();`  after `loggedInEmployee`

Comment: I think this fixed it! Thank you so much for your quick responses and help :)

Comment: Glad to help you out, you can check more about [async-await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await) and [StatefulWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

`initState` call before building 1st frame and we have a `addPostFrameCallback` to load data. But `_loadDayTemplates()` method is outside the scope of callback. means it will only load on initState and wont refresh on `addPostFrameCallback`.

To load data and refresh the we need to include `_loadDayTemplates()` and use setState inside `addPostFrameCallback`.

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    loggedInEmployee =
        Employee.fromJson(jsonDecode(prefs.getString("employee")!));
 _loadDayTemplates(); // reload the templates
 setState((){}); refresh the UI
  });
  _loadDayTemplates();
}
```